# Display Contacts in A Jquerymobile Listview (phonegap)

Tags: cordova

Am trying to display all contacts in a jquerymobile listview.Unfortunately i only get one contact listed/displayed.
The code i used is below.Thanks

```
   function onDeviceReady() {
    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter=""; 
    options.multiple=true;
    var fields = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers", "photos"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

  // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
  //
   function onSuccess(contacts) {
   for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
    if(null != contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length;j++)
            {
           $('.real').append("<li'><a><img src='foto/user.png'/><h4 >" +    contacts[i].displayName +"</h4><p>"+ contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value +"</p></a>  </li>").listview('refresh');  

            }
        }
     }
 }
// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
 }
```

Comment: Searchng for the same issue.. Have you find a solution yet? Thanks!

Comment: YES, remove ".listview('refresh');".

Answer (score 0):

Although you have answered your own question, just to highlight on the issue I am adding my response.

From the [Docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html):

If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:

Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

For your question, you should do the below.

```
$('.real').listview('refresh');
```